# Having Run time check failure #2-stack around the variable "numbers"

Tags: c, error-handling, runtime-error

i have the input file as shown below

5

8

10

the actually face i need to read the file more lines the the above example.(without the space in between. Thus, i need to have the size of array depend on the lines of text file. this is the method i use by occur r

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *test;
    int numbers[]={0};
    int i=0;
    char *array1;
    if((test=fopen("Input1.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        array1 = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof (char));
        if((test=fopen("Input1.txt","r"))==NULL)
        {
            printf("File could not be opened\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(fgets(array1,(sizeof array1)-1,test)!=NULL) 
            {
                numbers[i]=atoi(array1);
                i++;
            }
            for(i=0;i<sizeof(array1)-1;i++)
            {
                printf("%d\n",numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    fclose (test);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    free(array1);
}
```

Comment: You're missing an element count in the definition of `numbers` (e.g. `numbers[1000]`).

Comment: but i need it to be vary with the text size. if the text size larger than what i have, then i will face a error also

Comment: @user15020809 Okay, so... dynamically allocate it. If needed, start it out at some fixed length. You can always extend it later using `realloc`.

Comment: how to extend it using realloc?? in this situation?

Comment: Docs on `realloc` are here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `sizeof` to do something it can't do.
`sizeof array1` is the size of the variable `array1`. Since it's defined as `char *`, the size is the size of the pointer (4 in 32bit systems, 8 in 64bit).
You obviously want the amount of allocated memory `array1` points to. But `sizeof` can't give it.

You need to use the size of the allocation - 1000 in your case. It's better to put it in a variable, instead of using the number 1000 in two places (because then, if you change one, you might forget to change the other).

Answer (score 0):

E.g

```
{
    FILE *test;
    int *numbers=NULL;
    int i=0,size=0;
    char array1[1000];//don't need dynamic allocate

    if((test=fopen("Input1.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(array1, sizeof(array1), test)!=NULL) 
        {
            numbers=(int*)realloc(numbers,sizeof(int)*(i+1));
            numbers[i++]=atoi(array1);
        }
        size=i;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",numbers[i]);
        }
        fclose(test);
        free(numbers);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```